# Android Studio error: static interface method invocations are not supported in -source 1.7

Tags: android, android-studio

> Error:(100, 48) error: static interface method invocations are not
>   supported in -source 1.7 (use -source 8 or higher to enable static
>   interface method invocations)

the line looks like this:

```
field = SomeInterface.someMethod("","","");
```

and the interface:

```
public interface SomeInterface extends AnotherInterface {
      public static SomeInterface someMethod(String arg1,String arg2,String arg3) throws IOException {
            return someMethod(arg1,arg2,arg3,SOME_CONSTANT,ANOTHER_CONSTANT);
      }
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Remove the `static` modifier obviously. Let a class implement an interface and the class' objects then have this method, not the class itself.

Comment: you can't. Android does not support Java 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since static interface method invocations were introduced in Java 8, you have to [add the Java 8 compatibility options](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) in your build.gradle file to enable Java 8 language features:

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
}
```

Comment: haven't tried it, but seems legit. Thanks for answering :)